# What is "deep fried" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have learned that "fried potatoes" is "frititaj terpomoj" in Esperanto. Are those "deep fried"?

In my native language (swedish) the terms for "putting food in a hot pan (possibly covered with some butter/fat)" and "submerge food in a pan of oil" are completely different. Hence there is no confusion between fried chicken and deep fried chicken. What about in Esperanto? Does "fritita kokaĵo" cover both or one of them?

Answer (score 6):

My impression is that not many languages make an easy distinction between "pan-fried" *(pate fritita)* and "deep-fried" *(pote fritita)* and that, consequently, *fritita* may mean either.

I have also seen "deep-fried" translated as *trempe fritita* (or just *trempfritita*) and *bane fritita*.

ESPDIC claims that *frituri* means "to deep-fry" and another Internet source claims that *friturujo* means "deep fryer". I am not sure of the origin of *fritur-* so for the machine I would suggest *fritujo*, *fritbano* or *fritmaŝino*.

Comment: My initial reaction to "tremp'" in this context is that the goal is to immerse the food in oil, not to soak it.

Comment: @TomasoAlexander If you immerse  food in oil, doesn't it normally get soaked with oil, even if partially?

Comment: @kiamlaluno if the oil is not hot enough it will get absorbed and make things oily, soggy, and gross. If it _is_ hot enough it will only absorb a small amount on the outside of the fried thing. This also depends on what that outside is. Batter absorbs more than raw flesh. Mostly though it's oil temperature that makes the big difference.

Comment: "Frituri" may come various languages. "Frituren" is "to deep fry" in Dutch and "frituur" means deep fried food or a snack bar, depending on the region. "Frittüre" is also "deep frying oil" in German, and "frityr" means "deep frying oil" in Norwegian and "deep frying" in Swedish according to Wikipedia. These words come from French, where "friture" means frying or fried food (not necessarily deep fried), and are related to "fritura" (Spanish and Portuguese for deep frying), and "frittura" (Italian for frying in general).

Answer (score 2):

I've been saying "profund-fritita" for years. I believe I picked it up from a French-English-Esperanto phrasebook made in Canada by someone of German extraction.